# Как записать символы/байты в начало файла не стирая имеющиеся данные?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток. Пытался сделать программу, в которой данные добавляются в начало файла. Натолкните на мыслю, с помощью каких классов и методов можно это реализовать? 
Пример моей реализации (не ругайте за плохой код, буду рад обоснованным замечаниям), при которой перезаписываются имеющиеся данные.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        File file = new File(reader.readLine());
        RandomAccessFile ramFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "w");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(reader.readLine());
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        while(inputStream.available() > 0){
            int count = inputStream.read(b);
            ramFile.seek(0);
            ramFile.write(b, 0, count);
        }
        reader.close();
        ramFile.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если именно вставить в начало, то либо либо сдвинуть существующие данные и потом записать в начало данные для вставки, либо писать в новый файл сначала данные для вставки, потом имеющиеся и потом удалить старый файл и переименовать новый в старый.

Comment: Способ с буфером я уже рассматривал, думаю должен быть способ по проще. Спасибо за идею!

Comment: Создать новый файл. Записать в него символы/байты, а потом старый файл. После старый файл удаляется/переименовывается в .bak, а новый приобретает оригинальное название старого

Answer (score 1):

Создаешь `ByteArrayOutputStream`. В него можно писать так же, как в `FileOutputStream`. Пишешь туда то, что нужно записать в начало файла. Затем открываешь поток на чтение файла и читаешь из него в этот `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Потом открываешь поток на запись в целевой файл и пишешь методом `writeTo(OutputStream out)`, указывая в качестве `out` свой `FileOutputStream`.
Пример (в IDE не запускал, возможно, есть синтаксические ошибки):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteArrayOutStream.write(someData); //someData - байты, которые нужно записать в начало файла
FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(myFile); //myFile - файл, в начало которого нужно дописать байты
while(fileIS.available() > 0)
    byteArrayOutStream.write(fileIS.read());
fileIS.close();
FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
byteArrayOutStream.writeTo(fileOS);
fileOS.close();
byteArrayOutStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Это код записи содержимого второго файла в начало первого файла. Получится что в первом файле с начало окажется содержимое второго файла а потом свое содержимое.

```
BufferedReader reader = new  BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String name1 = reader.readLine();
String name2 = reader.readLine();

FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader(name1);//поток чтения для первого файла

ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

while(fileReader1.ready()) {
    list2.add(fileReader1.read());
}
fileReader1.close();

FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(name1);//поток записи для первого файла
FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader(name2);//поток чтения для второго файла

while(fileReader2.ready()) {
    list1.add(fileReader2.read());
}
fileReader2.close();

for (int i=0; i<list2.size(); i++) {
    list1.add(list2.get(i));
}

for (int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++) {
    fileWriter.write(list1.get(i));
}
fileWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Оставлю это для тех, кому не принципиально не удалять инфу из  file1, а важно просто выполнить поставленную задачу и добавить информацию перед уже записанной.**

Можно создать список, в который сначала занести всю информацию из первого файла, потом из второго, а после этот список "затолкать" поверх уже имеющейся в первом файле информации:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String file1 = reader.readLine();
    String file2 = reader.readLine();

    try (BufferedReader secondFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
         BufferedReader firstFileRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
         BufferedWriter commonTextWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1))) {            
        List<String> commonText = new ArrayList<>();
        while (secondFileReader.ready()) {
            commonText.add(secondFileReader.readLine());
        }
        while (firstFileRead.ready()) {
            commonText.add(firstFileRead.readLine());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < commonText.size(); i++)
            commonTextWriter.write(commonText.get(i));
    }
}
```

Самое важное тут в строке:

```
BufferedWriter commonTextWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1)) {
```

В связи с отсутствием в конструкторе второго параметра true, информация в file1 сотрется и запишется новая.